# I have 2 objects that I want to combine, however when I press CTRL+J and try to paint my textures on one object, it is mirrored onto the other

Tags: mesh, texture-painting

I want to paint on the Mesh as if it were one. I click on both objects and press CTRL+J and I color. I color on one object and it is mirrored onto the others. How do I fix this to edit ONLY one part and not the others?

Comment: Were they full copies that were all sharing same texture map and texture image?

Comment: I dont think so.. Im kind of new to Blender but all I know is that I tried painting meshes that I have combined and it didnt work whenever I would use the Texture Paint. I dont entirely know what you mean.

Comment: Maybe share some screenshots or a sample blend file that has the same problem so we can look, I can try in the morning.